# How to play multiple sound at the same time using winsound module?

Tags: python

I tried running a background music, and if user hits space button, it would play a hit sound
But it didn't work

```
import turtle
import winsound

s = turtle.Screen()

winsound.PlaySound("bgm",winsound.SND_FILENAME)

def hitsound():
    winsound.PlaySound("hitsound1.wav".SND_NOSTOP)
turtle.listen()
s.onkeypress(hitsound, "space")
s.mainloop()
```

But this won't work
Please help me!
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

fix the

```
def hitsound():
    winsound.PlaySound("hitsound1.wav".SND_NOSTOP)
```

to this

```
def hitsound():
    winsound.PlaySound("hitsound1.wav",winsound.SND_NOSTOP)
```